# Why is this simple c scanf code causing infinite loop?

Tags: c, compilation, infinite-loop

first question on stack overflow for me, let's see how well this goes!

I can't understand why this simple piece of c code is causing an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  float num=0;
  printf("%f", num);
  scanf("%f", &num);
  printf("%f", num);
}
```

I checked out the other questions, but they were asking about why *entering illegal input types* causes an infinite loop.

My code causes an infinite loop upon *execution*, meaning it enters the loop before anything is even entered.

I compiled it like this:

```
gcc -o readSum readSum.c
```

Terminal output:

```
vim readSum.c
15jz4@hera:~$ gcc -o readSum readSum.c
15jz4@hera:~$ ./readSum
0.000000
```

-Nothing happens after pressing any keys
-Ctrl+Z exits the status but there could be some other key that stops it.
-Going to reinstall, until then...I can't c+p.

***EDIT***

Whoa...got responses pretty fast.

Really guys, what's up with the 'entire code' thing?  Why would I not put up my entire code? This is my entire code.  Or should I tell you I have the #include  at the top?

I created this just to test scanf.

That's exactly the point, for some reason after execution it just enters an infinite loop for no logical reason at all! I've tried int main() { }, ending it with return 0; without the scanf it works fine, like if I use any other functions like printf(...) but I can't figure out why immediately after I execute it, nothing happens, and I can only go back by using ctrl+z.  I compared it with other similar codes, can't see the reason.

No it is not sitting there waiting for input.  Literally the screen just goes out like it would in an infinite loop.

Judging by the comments there is nothing wrong with it logically then, it must be something in the background, like missing some library sources (although I don't think this is likely).

Nonononononono...why no images?? It would help the situation much!!

Comment: Show your _entire_ program.  You talk about a loop, but there is no loop here.

Comment: 1. Don't compile it like that, do it like this `gcc -Wall -Werror -o readSum readSum.c`. 2. There is no **loop** anywhere in that program. 3. Your `main()` prototype is wrong but you would know that if you compile it like I say.

Comment: Either explain that the code you show _is_ your entire source (and as if by magic, the loop occurs), or include the missing pieces (if there are any) that actually show the looping conditions.

Comment: "it enters the loop before anything is even entered". Do you mean the program just sits there waiting before any input is entered? That is exactly what `scanf` is supposed to do.

Comment: You actually should rarely post your _entire_ code .. you need to post enough code for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so others can (try to) reproduce your problem and diagnose it. The code you provided doesn't show a loop even though you talk about one. Perhaps the bug is in the loop, how can any of us know?

Comment: I mean why would I not post the entire code when it is this short and straightforward...never mind that.

Comment: if it's that short, then yes, edit your question and post the entire code, copy and paste, `#include`s and all, don't re-type. Also compile as @iharob suggested and fix all the warnings. As he stated your `main` prototype is wrong,, in this case it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: I think scanf is just hating on me or something, stuck on this for hours.  Since no one else has a problem (and glad I am for that, meaning nobody has to go through what I had to), this must mean something else is wrong then.

Comment: "why would I not post the entire code when it is this short and straightforward"  - you tell us... why didn't you post it?

Comment: copy and paste works for longer codes too, you know

Comment: @ M.M What do you mean? I did post it

Comment: @TestBug you just changed the code to have `#include <stdio.h>`. (Which is an important difference). Does your real code actually have it or not?

Comment: @iharob in C89 (and gnu89, which gcc defaults to), `main() {` is a valid definition

Comment: @M.M Yes, that is one thing I can confidently write down every single time I have to write anything.

Comment: What happens if you press `1` then Enter after running your program? Also I suggest you add a `printf` line like in Clara's example, then you will know whether the scanf has passed.

Comment: you can post images. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273878/c-wrong-output-value

Comment: @M.M Thank you for your help.  I added the printf and tried that, but it won't respond.  I will uninstall the system, and if it works then, the system must not have installed correctly in some ways which causes the loop.

Comment: @yano No, you need this thing called reputation.

Comment: @TestBug please answer the question: what happens if you press 1 then Enter after running your program?

Comment: ahh ,, well not much. My man over at that link is sitting at 1 rep right now,, that's after 5 DVs on that question though,, guess he can no longer post images. Yes I'm curious too, what's the answer to @M.M question?

Comment: Like I said in the very beginning.

Comment: Nothing works *sob*

Comment: "Nothing works" is useless. _What_ doesn't work? You press 1 and it doesn't appear on the screen? Did you add a `printf` to your program? You should add one before the `scanf` and after. Do either of those print? Do they infinitely print? _None_ of us are sitting beside you, we can't know a thing that's happening if you won't tell us. I'm starting to think you're just trolling at this point.

Comment: Run the program, then copy and paste the output from your terminal.  That will give us a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: @yano Yes, I press 1 and it doesn't appear on the screen.  Yes, I added the printf.  The printf before the scanf does.  The printf after it doesn't.  Nothing prints and nothing can be done until you press ctrl+z.  I would thank you for not accusing me of being a troll, sir, my day is bad enough without that.

Comment: Finally, some information! Ok, so the `printf` before the `scanf` prints,, just once I'm assuming? That discards the possibility of an infinite loop. You press '1' and it doesn't appear on the screen .. are you sure the terminal window you're trying to type into has focus? Guess it does if Ctrl+Z does something. No keys you type appear on the screen? Ctrl+Z is the only key presses that you know of that garner a response? And update your question with the **exact** code you are now running and it's output.

Comment: Did you press the enter key after pressing 1?

Comment: @dbush Yeah I did...maybe it's just being stupid and takes really long to process this incredibly short command?

Comment: I do have smt to work on, I'll wait till it's finished reinstalling, and then I'll get back...

Comment: Did you link in the math library?  `gcc -o readSum readSum.c` appears to be missing that.

Comment: When you print, include a newline at the end of the format string.  Do that in the `printf()` before the `scanf()`, and in the `printf()` after.  You show the `0.000000` output; you don't seem to show an input value.  Did you actually type `3.141593` or some other value into the program?  You should be using something like: `if (scanf("%f", &num) != 1) printf("Read failed\n"); else `printf("Value: %f\n", num);` testing whether the input works. When I run the code shown in the question, I can type 3.14159 after the 0.000000 and then I see 3.141590 followed immediately by my command-line prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine actually. Even added a print statement to check. I think you're confusing inputting a number with an infinite loop because there is no loop to begin with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    float num = 0;
    scanf("%f", &num);
    printf("%f\n", num);
}
```

Try it out: https://ideone.com/RBDTYf

Comment: Saying that the code works is not an answer. It should just be a comment. When you get enough reputation you'll be able to comment on other people's questions. Until then, you should not abuse the answer method.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Barmar in this case, saying "there's no infinite loop in your code" is a reasonable answer IMO, and providing an MCVE since OP refuses to

Comment: It's not an answer. Obviously the question is incomplete, and the comments above are trying to get the poster to clarify it.

Comment: suggest initializing `num`, to avoid printing uninitiialized value in case `scanf` failed

Comment: @M.M Done. I put a "= 0" in there.